# Как найти общие символы в паре строк без учёта регистра?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Нужно найти общиe символы в двух строках без учёта регистра.

Как сравнить строки и вывести общиe символы?

```
>>>f('qqqwww', QQQasdf')
q
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а почему ассоциация? Формулировка вопросов сильно разная, и связь очень косвенная

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вопрос про ассоциацию всё ещё актуален, однако...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из многих возможных вариантов:

```
In [12]: set('qqqwww'.lower()) & set('QQQasdf'.lower())
Out[12]: {'q'}
```

в виде функции:

```
In [13]: def f(a, b):
    ...:     return set(a.lower()) & set(b.lower())
    ...:

In [14]: f('qqqwww', 'QQQasdf')
Out[14]: {'q'}
```

Comment: должно вывести q а не {q} или что либо ещо.
и нужно использовать методы строк. и что & Это такое?

Comment: @RostyslavPopov может так? `print ', '.join([a[0] for a in set('qqqewww'.lower()) & set('QQQeasdf'.lower())])`

Comment: @RostyslavPopov если вам нужно сравнение строк без учёта регистра, то используйте `str.casefold()` вместо `str.lower()`: set('qqqwww').intersection('QQaadf'.casefold())

Comment: @nobody чтобы напечатать `q`, если у вас есть `s = {'q'}`: `print(*s)`. Если в переменную хочется изъять значение: `q, = s` или `[q]=s`, если запятая не слишком приметна.

Comment: для сравнения текста без учёта регистра, [используйте как минимум `.casefold()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/589687/23044). `.lower()` не всегда работает для Unicode