# Как сравнить два списка на нахождение одного элемента который есть в первом и втором списке

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

То есть если представить это функцией, например:

```
def find_union(s1, s2):
```

какой-то код

и теперь я ввожу значения переменных, например:

```
find_union("aaabb", "bbbbccc")
```

я получаю: `b`

потому что оно встречается в первом и втором списке

Comment: Только это не *union*, а *intersect*. Реализовано во встроенной коллекции set. Т.е. результат это `list(set(s1) & set(s2))`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584634/Поиск-общих-елементов-символов-в-паре-строк-без-учёта-регистра/

Comment: @nobody в данном вопросе про регистр букв ничего не сказано.

Comment: @jfs ага, но похоже ведь :)

Comment: @nobody да вопросы очень похожи, но не точные дубликаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы найти хотя бы один символ `char`, общий для двух заданных строк `s1` и `s2`:

```
char, *rest = set(s1).intersection(s2)
```

Или если пересечение может быть больши́м, то чтобы раньше сравнение прекратить:

```
S = set(s1)
char = next(c for c in s2 if c in S)
```