# Нужно вывести все уникальные гласные буквы английского алфавита, со строки без учёта регистра

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
b = []
i = 0
a = 'programmer'
for a in a:
    if a[i] != 'a' or 'e' or 'y' or 'o' or 'u'  or 'i':
        del a[i]
    else:
         b = a[i]
    i+=1
print(b)
```

Comment: хорошо, на будущее учту

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [] # хранит результат
word = 'programmer' # входное слово
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'] # набор гласных
for ch in word.lower(): # перебираем все буквы входного слова
    if ch in vowels and ch not in result: # проверяем, есть ли буква с писке главных и не повторяется ли она в результате
        result.append(ch) # добавляем в результат

print(result)
>>> ['o', 'a', 'e']
```

Comment: в основном отвечает )

Comment: лучше проверять наоброт - не буквы из слова в списке, а буквы из списка в слове, тогда будет и кода меньше и самих проверок.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти набор гласных букв латинского алфавита, присутствующий в заданном тексте:

```
>>> text = "Yam, ﬁrﬆ, Ä, Ö, Ü, Å, Æ, and я"
>>> set("aeiouy").intersection(text.casefold())
{'a', 'i', 'y'}
```

Пример работает и для [лигатур](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2)) таких как `ﬁ`

Если не вызвать `.casefold()`, то результат:

```
>>> set("aeiouy").intersection(text)
{'a'}
```

`i`, `y` не найдены.

В зависимости от Unicode нормализации, буквы с акцентами, могут быть представлены как одним так и несколькими символами. Строки могут попадать в программу с разной нормализацией (к примеру на Маке, имена файлов представлены в форме близкой к NFD. В то время как на Linux, NFC может чаще встречаться). Это может привести к тому, что строки, которые выглядят идентично для человеческого глаза, воспринимаются компьютером как отличные. Чтобы учесть этот случай, можно использовать «каноническое сравнение без регистра» (canonical caseless matching), определённое в [секции 3.13 Unicode стандарта в D145](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#G33992):

```
import unicodedata

def NFD(text): 
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFD', text)

def canonical_caseless(text):
    return NFD(NFD(text).casefold())
```

Результат отличается от предыдущих:

```
>>> set("aeiouy").intersection(canonical_caseless(text))
{'a', 'u', 'o', 'y', 'i'}
```

Дополнительно найдены `'u'`, `'o'` буквы (так как эти буквы с акцентами представлены *двумя* символами в NFD—один из которых является буквой латинского алфавита)—желательно ли это для заданного ввода, зависит от конкретного рассматриваемого случая. NFD применяется дважды в D145, чтобы учесть крайне редкие крайние случаи такие как U+0345 (для латинских гласных можно не использовать).