# Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or

Tags: python, if, python-faq

Всем привет программируя на Python у меня возникла проблема с оператором 
if и его под функцией or при работе с str выглядит это примерно так

```
if a=="ноль" or "нулевой":
    print(0)
elif a=="один" or "единичный":
    print(1)
# выводит лишь 0 при любых значениях a
```

Что мне делать и как это исправить?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Многие начинающие программисты думают, что если написать

```
if a=="ноль" or "нулевой":
```

то `а` будет сравниваться поочередно с обеими частями - как с `"ноль"`, так и с `"нулевой"`.

```
if a=="ноль" или if a == "нулевой":
```

На самом деле исходная строчка не что иное, как

```
if (a=="ноль") or ("нулевой"):
```

Поэтому сравнение будет только одно: `a == "ноль"`. Вторая часть (`"нулевой"`) просто оценивается на логический результат, который в данном случае всегда True ([как и для любой другой непустой строки](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). А раз True, то выполнение всегда переходит к следующей строчке `print (0)` независимо от значения `а`.

Иными словами, строчка `if a=="ноль" or "нулевой"` эквивалентна строчке `if "нулевой"`. А т.к. результат такого выражения всегда True, то и эта строчка не нужна. Исходя из вышесказанного, все ваши четыре строчки эквивалентны одной:

```
print(0)
```

Именно это у вас и происходит.

Comment: Приятно читать такие хорошие объяснения.

Answer (score 25):

Вариант через оператор `in`:

```
if a in ("ноль", "нулевой"):
    print(0)
elif a in ("один", "единичный"):
    print(1)
```

---

Вариант через словарь:

```
name_by_value = {
    "ноль": 0,
    "нулевой": 0,
    "один": 1,
    "единичный": 1,
}

print(name_by_value[a])
```

Answer (score 15):

```
if a=="ноль" or a=="нулевой":
    print(0)
elif a=="один" or a=="единичный":
    print(1)
```