# Проверка на вхождение хотя бы одного из 3 значений в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Наверное есть ответ, но я видимо не верно формулирую вопрос, бросьте в меня ссылкой если так.

Есть такой код:

```
a = checkrp('12',x); b = checkrp('23',x)
if a or b in listrp: print(i,x)
#if b in listrp: print(i,x)
i += 1
x = func(x)
```

Когда значения `а` нет в списке, а `b` точно есть, вывод идет для `а`, но это не верно.

В результате приходится для каждого из значений делать отдельную итерацию по тому же самому списку, что не есть гуд.
Насколько я знаю, питон при проверке `а or b`, если `а` не в списке `b` не проверяет.

Вопрос как сделать проверку `(а or b or c) in list()`, чтобы точно было проверено вхождение каждого элемента и в случае истины выдавал результат.

Comment: `(а or b or c) in list() != (a in list()) or (b in list()) or (c in list())`

Comment: Вы неправильно интерпретируете то, как питон выполняет ``if a or b in listrp``.Почитайте:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or/846307#846307

Comment: в с++ просто проверяет в любом случае оба значения, а питон, как говорят ленивый)))

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью множества:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 9]
c = [8, 7, 6]

set(a).intersection(set(b))  # {1, 2} - True
set(a).intersection(set(c))  # {} - False
```

Comment: Да, этот метод работает быстрее

Comment: a, b, c это строки, я просто создаю промежуточный список из них.

Comment: @vbujym вариант с `set` переберет все элементы сета, в не зависимости найдено совпадение или нет, врямя прямо зависит от размера списков. Вариант с `__contains__` может закончить работу после первой же проверки, если совпадение сразу найдено.Так что утверждение что через set быстрее, очень спорно. Да к тому же set(a) - тоже займет лишнее время.

Comment: (1)проверка каждого элемента обязательна, (2)через set быстрее в 2 раза для моего случая - set из трех элементов проверяет по списку из ~11000 элементов ~2000 проверок в секунду,    ' __соntains__'      же делает примерно 1000 проверок с теми же данными по тому же самому списку. Согласен, хотелось бы большего, но я ограничен сверху 8000 проверок/сек.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [29]: array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [30]: a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

# если хотя бы 1 элемент входит
In [31]: any(map(array.__contains__, (a, b, c)))
Out[31]: True

# если все элементы входят
In [32]: all(map(array.__contains__, (a, b, c)))
Out[32]: True
```

Comment: работает, но не быстрее чем проверять через if a in list, if b in list..., map вроде как и работает поочередно по каждому значению со списком.

Comment: @vbujym ну по другому никак, у вас в вопросе не сказано что `a & b` -- списки.

Comment: a, b это строки ~40-50 символов. Ваш вариант считает примерно по 1000 проверок в секунду по списку в ~11000 значений. Метод со множеством считает 2000 проверки в секунду. Если убрать map может попробовать.

Comment: map убрать нельзя, но вариант списка все равно быстрее, проверяю не больше 1000 проверок в секунду

Comment: @vbujym в вопросе нужно было указать что такое `a b`