# Помочь разобраться с циклом Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

У меня есть три состояния ответа пользователя: "yes", "no" и любые другие ответы. Соответственно три ветки. Есть одна из трех веток, которая если user ввел что-либо кроме "yes" или "no" возвращает его в начало

```py
if autorisation  != 'no' and 'yes':

    while autorisation  != 'yes' and autorisation != 'no':

        print('Write only "yes" or "no". Try again')
        autorisation = str(input("Are you registered? :")).lower().replace(" ","")
```

Мне не хватает знаний и умения чтобы сделать код красивым и читаемым. Если использовать `else` то мы не вернемся в начало ветвления

Comment: `input()` возвращает строку. Зачем Вы строку кастуете к строке?

Comment: ``if autorisation  != 'no' and 'yes':`` - в этой строке ошибка. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or/846307#846307 И str в строке с input не требуется.

Answer (score 3):

```
while True:
    autorisation = input("Are you registered? :").lower().replace(" ","")

    if autorisation=='no' or autorisation=='yes':
        break
```

Comment: ну str то лишнее :)

Comment: да, лишнее. Исправлено, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь бы помог `do..while`, но такого цикла в Python нет, так что:

```py
autorisation = str(input("Are you registered? :")).lower().replace(" ","")

while (autorisation  != 'yes') and (autorisation != 'no'):

        print('Write only "yes" or "no". Try again')
        autorisation = str(input("Are you registered? :")).lower().replace(" ","")
```

Этот код сначала спрашивает. Если неверно – повторяет, если верно – условие цикла не выполняется и выполнение программы идёт дальше.

Если вместо строки `autorisation = str(input("Are you registered? :")).lower().replace(" ","")` был бы большой многострочный блок кода, его следовало бы вынести в отдельную функцию по принципу DRY.

Answer (score 1):

```
def asksYesNo(question):
    response = None
    while response not in ('yes', 'no'):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response
```

Comment: после ``.lower()`` результат ``response not in ('Yes', 'No')`` будет всегда true.

Comment: Все исправил, обычная невнимательность)

Comment: @МишаМладший и что тогда делать с этой строкой ? ```print('Write only "yes" or "no". Try again') ```

Comment: @MusterYoooda можно так askYesNo('You a registered? Write only yes or no: ')

Comment: @МишаМладший Так не пойдет(( Я поэтому и не использовал там функцию

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете определить варианты, при которых нужно прекратить запрашивать ответы в отдельную переменную. Чтобы не тратить время выполнения на создание объекта, варианты стоит определить за за пределами цикла.

Далее в вечном цикле запрашиваете ответ на вопрос. Если введенное значение совпало с одним из вариантов (конструкция qanswer in variants`), то прекращаете цикл словом` break`.

Так как введенное значением может содержать проблемы и разный регист, введеное значение надо преобразовать в оптимальный формат. В данном случае привели строку в нижний регистр (`.lower()`) и убрали пробелы перед и после введенных симоволов (`.strip()`)

Код примера ниже

```
variants = ('yes', 'no',)
while True:
    answer = input("Are you registered? :").lower().strip()
    if answer in variants:
        break
print('Ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

if autorisation  != 'no' and 'yes':
не имеет смысла так как не пустая строка возвращает истину то есть смысл этого выражения не изменится убрав and 'yes'

по вопросу:

```
while au:=str(input('yes\no? :')).lower() not in ['yes','no','not','n','y']:
   print('u write'+str(au)+'it is not yes or not')

if au in 'yes':
   print('letter y in yes then only one expression needed')
```