# Как работает код условие "if pogoda == 10 or 11 or 12"

Tags: python-3.x

У меня проблема с кодом `print("It work")` постоянно срабатывает при любом значении `pogoda`

```
pogoda = 2
if pogoda == 10 or 11 or 12:
    print("It work")
else:
    print("It not work")
```

Comment: if pogoda == 10 or 11 or 12: означаяет  if (pogoda == 10) or 11(true) or 12(true). Правильно типа if pogoda in (10 ,11 ,12 )

Comment: Надо везде прописывать *pogoda ==*,  или напишите *if pogoda in [10, 11, 12]*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 2):

Условие `pogoda == 10 or 11 or 12` выполняется не так, как Вы задумывали.

Сначала проверяется истинность выражения `pogoda == 10`, потом истинность числа `11` и числа `12`.

Число `11` всегда истинно (`bool(11) == True`), поэтому и выражение будет истинно всегда.

Можно написать `if pogoda == 10 or pogoda == 11 or pogoda == 12:`, но это длинный вариант, лучше используйте:

```py
if pogoda in (10, 11, 12):
    print("It work")
else:
    print("It not work")
```

Answer (score -2):

можно и конкретно через `==` т.е. `__eq__`

```
if any(map(pogoda.__eq__, (10, 11, 12))):
    print("It work")
else:
    print("It not work")
```