# Не могу понять в чем ошибка. print не показывакт big и small number

Tags: python

Мне нужно заполнить 3 переменные через input. Вывести самое большое и самое маленькое.
Никак не могу понять, что делаю не так.

```
try:
num_1 = int(input('1 number'))
num_2 = int(input('2 number'))
num_3 = int(input('3 number'))
if num_1 > num_2 and num_3:
    num_1 = big_num
    if num_1 < num_2 and num_3:
        num_1 = small_num
        if num_2 > num_1 and num_3:
            num_2 = big_num
            if num_2 < num_1 and num_3:
                num_2 = small_num
                if num_3 > num_1 and num_2:
                    num_3 = big_num
                    if num_3 < num_1 and num_2:
                        num_3 = small_num
                        print(big_num, small_num)
                    else:
                        None
                else:
                    None  
            else:
                None
        else:
            None
    else:
        None    
else:
    None     
except ValueError:
       print('Только числа:')
```

Comment: Если `num_1` не больше, чем `num_2`, то у вас ничего не выведется, потому что все остальные условия у вас внутри первого.

Comment: А ещё почитайте этот вопрос и ответы -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/282277 Там про or, но никаких различий с and нет.

Comment: А если else: None, то можно это не писать. Никакой пользы, только захламляет код.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы делаете что-то невероятно сложное.

Предлагаю воспользоваться функциями `min` и `max`.

***Пример:***

```py
num_1 = int(input('1 number: '))
num_2 = int(input('2 number: '))
num_3 = int(input('3 number: '))

nums = [num_1, num_2, num_3]

print('Max:', max(nums))
print('Min:', min(nums))
```

Или ещё короче:

```py
nums = [int(input(f'{i+1} number: ')) for i in range(3)]

print('Max:', max(nums))
print('Min:', min(nums))
```