# Как проверить наличие сразу двух переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пользователь должен ввести сначала номер страницы, а потом номер задания на этой странице, а программа проверяет есть ли на данной странице данное задание. Как это правильней реализовать? Пытаюсь сделать это через списки и zip, но не понимаю как это работает

```py
pages = ['125', '132']
tasks = [['2', '3', '4', '5'],
         ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

while True:
    page_number = input('Для начала работы выберите номер страницы: ')
    if page_number.isdigit():
        if page_number in pages:
            task_number = input('Теперь выберите номер задачи: ')
            if page_number and task_number in list(zip(pages,tasks)):
                break
            else:
                print('Такой задачи либо нет на этой странице, либо она не решена!')
        else:
            print('На этой странице нет заданий, либо задания на ней еще не решены!')
    else:
        print('Введите правильный номер страницы!')
```

Comment: Приведите пример правильного и неправильного ввода.

Comment: Ещё почитайте здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/282277 Там про or, но к and тоже относится

Answer (score 0):

Я почитал про словари и реализовал проверку через это. Возможно это не самый рациональный путь, но я хотя бы разобрался. Всем спасибо за помощь

```py
pages = {'125':['1','2','3'],
         '132':['2','3','4']}

while True:
    page_number = input('Для начала работы выберите номер страницы: ')
    if page_number.isdigit():
        if page_number in pages:
            tasks = pages.get(page_number)

            task_number = input('Теперь выберите номер задачи: ')

            if task_number in tasks:
                break
            else:
                 print('Такой задачи либо нет на этой странице, либо она не решена!')
        else:
            print('На этой странице нет заданий, либо задания на ней еще не решены!')
    else:
        print('Введите правильный номер страницы!')
```