# Помогите решить проблему на Python

Tags: python

Почему не работает код?
Пишет elif a >= 10 and <= 19:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
a = int(input('Количество пакетов'))
TOVAR = 99

if a < 10:
    print('Нету скидки')
    b = a * TOVAR
    print(b)
elif a >= 10 and <= 19:
    print('Скидка 10%')
    b = a * TOVAR
    c = b * 0.10
    print('Вся сума с скидкою', c)
elif a >= 20 and <= 49:
    print('Скидка 20%')
    b = a * TOVAR
    c = b * 0.20
    print('Вся сума з скидкою', c)
elif a >= 50 and <= 99:
    print('Скидка 30%')
    b = a * TOVAR
    c = b * 0.30
    print('Вся сума с скидкою', c)
elif a >= 100:
    print('Скидка 40%')
    b = a * TOVAR
    c = b * 0.40
    print('Вся сума с скидкою', c)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Comment: надо указывать переменную при сравнении: `elif a >= 10 and a <= 19`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как и писали выше, потеряли переменную**

```py
a, TOVAR = int(input('Количество пакетов : ')), 99
if a < 10:
    print('Нет скидки\n{}'.format(a * TOVAR))
elif a >= 10 and a <= 19:
    print('Скидка 10%\nВся сума с скидкой : {}'.format(a * TOVAR * 0.1))
elif a >= 20 and a <= 49:
    print('Скидка 20%\nВся сума с скидкой : {}'.format(a * TOVAR * 0.2))
elif a >= 50 and a <= 99:
    print('Скидка 30%\nВся сума с скидкой : {}'.format(a * TOVAR * 0.3))
elif a >= 100:
    print('Скидка 40%\nВся сума с скидкой : {}'.format(a * TOVAR * 0.4))
```