# Нахождение наибольшего общего делителя

Tags: python

При вводе 12 и 16, мне выводится 8, хотя 12 на 8 не делится

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
x = int
u = []
if a > b:
    x = b
else:
    x = a


for i in range(2, x + 1):
    if a and b % i == 0:
        u = u + [i]
print(max(u))
print(u)
```

Comment: обратите внимание на строчку ``if a and b % i == 0:`` и на этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or/846307#846307

Comment: Этот код выводит максимальный делитель второго числа, который не больше первого числа.

Comment: for i in range(2, x + 1):
    if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0: # !!!
        u = u + [i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте рекурсией.

```
def gcd(num1, num2):
    res = num1 % num2
    if res == 0:
        return num2
    else:
        return gcd(num2, res)
```

Тест:

```
print(gcd(4,12))
#4
print(gcd(255,21))
#3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2, x + 1):
    if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0: # !!!
        u = u + [i]
```

Comment: я всё изменил и не работает