# Python, как if - in в списках работает?

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
datap1 = ["a3","a2","b2"]

if "a1" in datap1:
    print("1")
if "a2" in datap1:
        print("2")
if "a3" in datap1:
        print("3")
if "b1" in datap1:
        print("4")
if "b2" in datap1:
        print("5")
if "b3" in datap1:
        print("6")
if "c1" in datap1:
        print("7")
if "c2" in datap1:
        print("8")
if "c3" in datap1:
        print("9")



if ("a1" and "b1" and "c1") or ("a2" and "b2" and "c2") or ("a3" and "b3" and "c3") or ("a1" and "a2" and "a3") or ("b1" and "b2" and "b3") or ("c1" and "c2" and "c3") or ("a1" and "b2" and "c3") or ("c1" and "b2" and "a3") in list(datap1):
        print('Игрок выиграл!')
        exit()
else:
    print("game over")
```

И по логике должно выводиться в конце **game over**, а выводится **Игрок выиграл**!

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь с кодом(чтобы он при только условии выводил Игрок выиграл!)

И пожалуйста объясните, как реализовывать условия с `and` и `or` в списках.

Заранее ,спасибо!

Ps. Гуглил, ответа не нашёл

Comment: Что-то с пробелами не все понятно. Отформатируйте нормально, пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне надо чтобы при фрагмент кода активировался при наличии в нём 3-х  определённыхэлементов,а при неактивации  писалось другое значение.

Comment: Так как вы написали - нельзя. Лучше всего циклом это проверять. К слову, операторы and и or берут аргументы слева и справа, приводят к булевому значению (True или False), и вычисляет новое булевое значение. Т.к. любая непустая строка эквивалентна True, то ваше длинное выражение сокращается до `if True in list(datap1):`, что равно False, если у вас в списке не было True.

Comment: Хотя нет, получится `if 'c1' in list(datap1):`, но думаю это тоже не то что вам было нужно)

Comment: Понятно, но можете, пожалуйста, привести пример, как надо было это сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Comment: По логике как раз не должно. И надо не гуглить неизвестно что, а читать литературу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу задачу проще всего решить как-то так:

```
datap1 = ["a3","a2","b2"]

# Здесь перечислены все выигрышные варианты
win_variants = [
    ("a1", "b1", "c1"),
    ("a2", "b2", "c2"),
    ("a3", "b3", "c3"),
    ("a1", "a2", "a3"),
    ("b1", "b2", "b3"),
    ("c1", "c2", "c3"),
    ("a1", "b2", "c3"),
    ("c1", "b2", "a3"),
]


check = any(len(set(datap1) & set(variant)) == 3
            for variant in win_variants)

if check:
    print('Игрок выиграл!')
else:
    print("game over")
```

А что касается операторов and и or, то нужно просто понять, что они работают не так, как `и`/`или` в обычной речи. Есть чёткие правила, как они работают, которые нужно просто прочитать и запомнить. А не пытаться дословно переводить фразу с русского на питон.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так(Не претендую на самый удобный вариант))):

```py
datap1 = ["a1","a2","a3"]
c = 'Игрок выиграл'
z = 0
check = [["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"],["c1","c2","c3"],["a1","b1","c1"],['a2','b2','c2'],['a3','b3','c3'],['a1','b2','c3'],['c1','b2','a3']]

def CHecks(check, data1):
    for z in check:
        if (z == data1):
            a = 'Игрок выиграл'
            return a
    a = "Game over"
    return a

print(CHecks(check, datap1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильная проверка должна выглядеть вот так для вашего кода:

```
if (("a1" in datap1) and ("b1" in datap1) and ("c1" in datap1)) or (
        ("a2" in datap1) and ("b2" in datap1) and ("c2" in datap1)) or (
        ("a3" in datap1) and ("b3" in datap1) and ("c3" in datap1)) or (
        ("a1" in datap1) and ("a2" in datap1) and ("a3" in datap1)) or (
        ("b1" in datap1) and ("b2" in datap1) and ("b3" in datap1)) or (
        ("c1" in datap1) and ("c2" in datap1) and ("c3" in datap1)) or (
        ("a1" in datap1) and ("b2" in datap1) and ("c3" in datap1)) or (
        ("c1" in datap1) and ("b2" in datap1) and ("a3" in datap1)):
    print('Игрок выиграл!')
    # exit()
else:
    print("game over")
```

Пусть монструозно, но в данном варианте проверяется каждое из вхождений с условиями.
Что же касается `and`/`or` - тут изначально в вашем варианте выполняется не совсем то, чего вы ожидали.
Данная конструкция: `("a1" and "b1" and "c1")` выполняет сравнение конкретных строк между собой. Следовательно у вас находилось "самая большая" строка из всех вариантов, а не объединение строк в нужную комбинацию.

Comment: Не "самая большая". Для and это будет последняя строка (последний операнд), если все условие истинное (или первый встретившийся ложный операнд). Например результат выражения `"c1" and "b1" and "a1"` будет `"a1"`, а результат `"c1" and "" and "a1"` будет `''`.