# не выводится выбор через оператора "or"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я попыталась сделать программу, которая будет определять время года по месяцу, но в итоге оператор 'or' выводит только зиму

```
print('Хотите узнать какое сейчас время года?\n"Да" или "Нет"?\n')
select = input()

if select.lower() == 'да':
    print('Введите месяц: ')
    select2 = input()

    if select2.lower == 'Декабрь' or 'Янаварь' or 'Февраль':
        print('Сейчас время года: Зима')

    elif select2.lower == 'Май' or 'Апрель' or 'Март':
        print('Сейчас время года: Весна')

    elif select2.lower == 'Август' or 'Июль' or 'Июнь':
        print('Сейчас время года: Лето')

    elif select2.lower == 'Сентябрь' or 'Октябрь' or 'Ноябрь':
         print('Сейчас время года: Осень')

elif select.lower() == 'нет':
    print('Хорошо')
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно отметили вы не верно создали сложное условие.

Могу рекомендовать не использовать каскад условий, это затрудняет и модификацию кода и его чтение. Если у вас в простой задаче более трех вложений условий, значит что-то пошло не так)

В вашем случае четыре отдельных условных оператора ни чуть не хуже.

Можно создать словарь:

```
  m_to_season={ 'январь' :'зима', 'февраль' :'зима', 'март' :'весна', 'апрель' :'весна', 'май' :'весна', 'июнь' :'лето' ,'июль' :'лето', 'август' :'лето', 'сентябрь' :'осень', 'октябрь' :'осень', 'ноябрь' :'осень',  'декабрь' :'зима'}

 print('Введите месяц: ')
 select2 = input()
 if   select2.lower() in m_to_season.keys():
     print(m_to_season[select2.lower()]) 
 else:
     print('none')
```

Comment: вместо `if` можно использовать метод `get` класса `dict`.  
`print(m_to_season.get(select2.lower(), 'Нет такого месяца'))`

Answer (score -1):

```
select2.lower in ('декабрь', 'янаварь', 'февраль')
```