# Несколько условий python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, распознавание-речи

Есть список `mis`, который в себе содержит распознанные слова. При запуске код игнорирует любые слова в списке и выполняет действия при первом условии (строки 2-4).

```
def do(mis):
    if ('открой' or 'запусти' or 'open' in mis):
        say('секунду...')
        open(mis)
    elif 'остановись' in mis:
        print('Без Б')
        say("Код остановлен")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        do(hear())
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему он выполняет первое условии, если в листе не было слов из условия?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы было несколько вариантов слов для в условии для исполнения?

Хотелось бы решение без повторения `in mi` как ниже:

```
if ('открой' in mis or 'open' in mis):
    say("секунду...')
...
```

Comment: `if any(word in mis for word in ('открой', 'запусти', 'open'))`.

Comment: Выполняется первое условие, потому что оно равносильно (**условно**) `if ("открой") or if ("запусти") or if("open" in mis)`. Т.е., в первую очередь проверяется просто строка, а любая непустая строка это `True`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 1):

1. Непустая строка всегда истинна в питоне. Стало быть:
   `'открой' or 'запусти' or 'open'` — Всегда True.
2. Вы хотите:

```
if any(word in mis for word in ('открой', 'запусти', 'open')):
...
```

OR

```
if any(map(lambda word: word in mis, ('открой', 'запусти', 'open'))):
...
```