# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). Codewars

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код работает, но на CODEWARS Выводит ниже приписка и поэтому не получается cдать кату:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(comp(a1, a2), False)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 4, in comp
    if len(a) != len(b):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

```
#Сравнивает два списка, второй должен состоять из квадратов первого, тогда True
def comp(a, b):
    if a and b is None:
        return True
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    index = 0
    n = 0
    while index != len(a):
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            if a[index]**2 == b[i]:
                n += 1
                continue
            else:
                continue
        if n != len(a):
            index += 1
    if n/2 == len(a):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `a and b is None` работает как `a and (b is None)` (т.к. у `is` приоритет выше чем у `and`). Чтобы проверить, что и `a` и `b` являются `None`, нужно написать `a is None and b is None`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите эту фразу: _на CODEWARS Выводит ниже приписка и поэтому не получается cдать кату_, на русский.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def comp(a, b):
    if a is None and b is None:
        return True
    if a is None or b is None or len(a) != len(b):
        return False            
    return sorted(list(map(lambda x: x**2, a))) == sorted(b)
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [24]: comp([], [1,2])
Out[24]: False

In [25]: comp([], [])
Out[25]: True

In [26]: comp([4, 2, 3], [9, 16, 4])
Out[26]: True
```

Comment: Лучше обьяснить новичку, что `if a and b is None` не работает так как он думает, чем `None in [a,b]`

Comment: @SKIP, если разбирать код топикстартера, то там достаточно много придется объяснять - почему так делать не надо. Проще и быстрее показать как сделать правильно...

Comment: и смысл от этого, если в другой задаче автор напишет похожий `if` и не будет понимать почему не работает?

Comment: Не рабоет на примере

a = [-121, -144, 19, -161, 19, -144, 19, -11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
'''

Comment: @Rollan, исправил - при наличии отрицательных чисел сортировать нужно было __после__ возведения в квадрат