# Сложное условие в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Возникала задача написать на Python сложное условие (наверное так это можно назвать). В общем, вот как я хотел-бы сделать (объясню псевдокодом):

```
if 'привет как дела' или 'как дела привет' in task:
    print('Все отлично' или 'У меня все хорошо' или 'просто замечательно')
```

Конечно, я пробовал писать вместо "или" "or",но, к сожалению, по понятным причинам, так не работает...

Мне бы очень хотелось узнать как можно реализовать задуманное?

Comment: if 'привет как дела' in task or 'как дела привет' in task

Comment: как должна работать программа, если в `task` будет подстрока `дела как, привет` ;)

Comment: MaxU, так не сработает. Для этого можно использовать Fuzzy wuzzy. Метод нечеткого или не точного сравнения. Очень хороший модуль, отлично работает. Я потом своего голосового ассистента переделаю на этот модуль, тогда будет отлично работать, а пока только несколько вариантов точных фраз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выбора ответа воспользуйтесь встроенным [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

if 'привет как дела' in task or 'как дела привет' in task:
    print(random.choice(['Все отлично', 'У меня все хорошо', 'просто замечательно']))
```

PS по поводу if 'str' in task or ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846307/420098)

Comment: За PS отдельное спасибо. Я не смог "нагуглить" эту информацию.