# Ошибка вида NameError: name 'k' is not defined

Tags: python

Какие могут быть причины ошибки,я не понимаю,за ответ спасибо
Выдается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 10, in <module>
    k=k+1
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

код:

```
 print('Введите стих построчно,отделяя строки нажатием Enter,'   
      'последней строкой введите Конец')
while(1 == 1):
   s = str(input())
   if(s == 'Конец') or ('КОНЕЦ') or ('конец'):
    break
    k = 0
for x in s:
    if(x in 'ауеоыяиюУЕЫАОЭЯИЮ'):
        k=k+1
print(k)
```

Comment: Сначала исправьте табуляции. В Питоне табуляции очень важны, в таком виде у вас программа не заработает. И скорее всего у строки `k = 0` вообще не должно быть отступа.

Comment: И что бы не изобретать велосипед и писать много "Конец" с разными заглавными буквами, можешь использовать upper на input и с проверкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
break
k = 0
```

эти строки надо поменять местами

```
if(s == 'Конец') or ('КОНЕЦ') or ('конец'):
```

так писать не правильно, советую прочитать: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/400096)

Comment: начерное, лучше k = 0 поставить перед while?

Comment: @Jack_oS возможно

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете и переопределяете ременную в цикле.

```py
print('Введите стих построчно,отделяя строки нажатием Enter,'   
      'последней строкой введите Конец')
k = 0  # Добавленная строка
while True:  # Смысл в 1 == 1? итогом будет True
    s = input() # По умолчанию str приводить не обязательно
    if s.lower() == 'конец': # Сравниваем с s
        break
for x in s:
    if x in 'ауеоыяиюУЕЫАОЭЯИЮ':
        k=k+1
print(k)
```

P.S. s у вас каждый раз перезаписывается так что всегда будет только последний ввод

Answer (score 0):

Немного пофантазировал на ТЕМУ:

```py
print('Введите стих построчно, отделяя строки нажатием Enter.\n'
      'последней строкой введите "Конец"')

vowels = 'ауеоыяиюУЕЫАОЭЯИЮ'
lines = ''
while (line := input(': ')).lower() != 'конец':
    lines += line
print(sum([letter in vowels for letter in lines]))
```