# Баг в калькуляторе

Tags: python, калькулятор

Пытался писать кальулятор, но при вводе символов `**` производится операция извлечения корня `**.` что делать?

```
import sys  #Импортирование модуля sys
import math #Импортирование модуля math
from math import pi #Из модуля math импортирование функции pi
def calculator() : #Создание функции калькулятор
    print('Enter operation symbol : ')
    operationsymbol = input() #Создание переменной с символом операции
    if operationsymbol == 'pi': #Число пи
        print(pi)
        sys.exit() #Преждевременный выход из выполнения скрипта
    print('Enter x : ')
    x = float(input()) #Создание переменной с первым числом, переведение его в другой тип данных: float
    if operationsymbol == '**.' or 'root of the equation':
        answer = math.sqrt(x) #Получение квадратного корня уравнения
        print(answer)
        sys.exit() #Преждевременный выход из выполнения скрипта
    print('Enter : ')
    y = float(input())
    if operationsymbol == '+': #Сложение чисел
        answer = x + y
    elif operationsymbol == '-': #Вычитание чисел
        answer = x - y
    elif operationsymbol == '*': #Умножение чисел
        answer = x * y
    if operationsymbol == '**': #Возведение чисел в степень
        answer = pow(x, y)
    elif operationsymbol == '/' or ':': #Деление чисел
        answer = x / y
    else:
        print('Ouch...Something went wrong') #Ошибка
    print('Ответ : ' + str(answer)) #Выведение ответа

print(calculator()) #Вызов функции калькулятор
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 1):

*Не правильное условие здесь:*

```
if operationsymbol == '**.' or 'root of the equation':
```

*Так попробуйте*

```
if operationsymbol == '**.' or operationsymbol == 'root of the equation':
```

Доказательство:

```
In [4]:  string = "**"
In [5]: if string == "**." or "*":
   ...:     print("Истина")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("Ложь")
   ...:
Истина

In [6]: if string == "**." or "":
   ...:     print("Истина")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("Ложь")
   ...:
Ложь
```

То есть пустая строка ложь а не пустая истина.

Comment: Вообще словами опишите что вы хотите сделать в этом условии.

Comment: тоже самое в проверке оператора деления

Comment: Да всё верно, ладно думаю далее автор вопроса сам разберётся.