# Строка как условие в условном операторе Python

Tags: if, условия, операторы

**Цель кода:** организовать диалог с пользователем - введение в структуру чат-бота на основе работы условного оператора.

С клавиатуры пользователь должен ввести название комнаты, а в условном операторе, в котором как условие задана строка, должна быть осуществлена проверка названия комнаты и выведено ее описание.
Проблема в том, что какую бы я не вводила комнату, выводится результат первой поверки - описание спальни.

Помогите исправить, чтобы при вводе названия комнаты выводилось именно её описание. Не могу понять, в чем проблема :(

```
room = str(input())
if room == 'спальня' or 'о спальне':
    print('В нашей спальне есть умный диван. Он способен распознавать голос человека и считывать его степень усталости. По команде человека он трансформируется в огромный диван для большой компании, в двухэтажную кровать для экономии места, а ночью  в диван-кровать. Также в него встроен ортопедический матрац, который позволяет хозяевам сохранять здоровье спины. Жаль что на моё мяуканье еще реагировать не научился.')
elif room == 'кухня' or 'о кухне':
    print('Наша умная кофеварка к определенному времени готовит кофе по требованию хозяев. А еще она умеет готовить несколько чашек кофе сразу без участия человека. Она настолько умная, что автоматически убирает чашки со своей панели и заранее предупреждает, что скоро закончится сахар или зерна.')
elif room == 'ванная' or 'о ванной' or 'ванная комната':
    print('Наше умное зеркало подбирает макияж и прическу под образ человека, а также помогает нарисовать идеальные стрелки и симметричные брови. Моя хозяйка этому очень рада!')
else:
    print('В нашем доме нет такой комнаты.')
```

Comment: if room == 'спальня' or room == 'о спальне', а лучше, наверное, if 'спальн' in room

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/420098 и это почитайте

Comment: @Jack_oS, большое спасибо!

Comment: и для input() не нужен str(), он и так вернет строку, а вот привести ее к нижнему регистру room = input().lower() не помешает