# Алгоритм присвоения победы в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Я создаю игру крестики-нолики. Мне надо ввести проверку на победную комбинацию. При компиляции кода, победной комбинацией является только последний if, а первый пропускается, а это я только считываю победу крестиков без учета комбинаций по диагонали.

```
procedure TForm1.win;
var 
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 3 do
    if gg[i,1] and gg[i,2] and gg[i,3]=1 then 
    begin
      final:=true
    end 
    else
    begin
      if gg[1,i] and gg[2,i] and gg[3,i]=1 then 
      begin
        final:=true;
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: Плохие новости - последний иф тоже пропускается. Хорошие новости - это легко исправить. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-or/ Там про питон и про or, но разницы никакой нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 0):

Попрактикую телепатию.

```
for i:=1 to 3 do
   if (gg[i,1]=1) and (gg[i,2]=1) and (gg[i,3]=1) then 
      final:=true
   else
     if (gg[1,i]=1) and (gg[2,i]=1) and (gg[3,i]=1) then 
       final:=true;
```

Наверное, лучше будет так:

```
for i:=1 to 3 do
   if (gg[i,1]=1) and (gg[i,2]=1) and (gg[i,3]=1) or 
      (gg[1,i]=1) and (gg[2,i]=1) and (gg[3,i]=1) then begin 
       final:=true;
       break;
   end;
```