# Как сделать так, чтобы программа выводила приветствие, только когда пользователь пишет "Привет" или "Здравствуйте"?

Tags: python, datetime, if, условия

```
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
a = str(input())

if hour < 12:
    greeting = "Доброе утро"
elif hour < 18:
    greeting = "Добрый день"
else:
    greeting = "Добрый вечер"
        
if a == "Привет" or "Здравствуйте":
    print("{}!".format(greeting))
```

Comment: Код выводит приветствие в не зависимости от того что ты написал

Comment: `if a in ["Привет", "Здравствуйте"]:`, а вообще подобные вопросы много раз задавали

Comment: Можно и с `or` оставить, но тогда справа от `or` надо написать полное сравнение ещё раз: `or a == ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = input()  # input() сразу возвращает строку
```

проверяйте или так:

```
if a == "Привет" or a == "Здравствуйте":
    print("{}!".format(greeting))
```

или так:

```
if a in ["Привет", "Здравствуйте"]:
    print("{}!".format(greeting))
```

т.е.:

```
from datetime import datetime


hour = datetime.now().hour
a = input()

if hour < 12:
    greeting = "Доброе утро"
elif hour < 18:
    greeting = "Добрый день"
else:
    greeting = "Добрый вечер"

if a in ["Привет", "Здравствуйте"]:
    print(f"{greeting}!")
```

Ассоциация: [проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846307/420098)