# Не работает механизм подбора сочетаний одежды

Tags: python

У меня есть вот такой код, который подбирает сочетания верхней и нижней одежды, но печатает он только те, в которых есть одежда из списка *favourites*

```
bottom_clothes = ('jeans', 'shorts', 'skirt')
top_clothes = ('t-shirt', 'bra', 'top', 'jacket')
favourites = ('jeans')

for cloth in bottom_clothes:
    for top_cloth in top_clothes:
        for fav in favourites:
            if fav == cloth or top_cloth:
                print(f'Try {cloth} with {top_cloth}')
                break
```

Но по итогу код выдает вот это

```
Try jeans with t-shirt
Try jeans with bra
Try jeans with top
Try jeans with jacket
Try shorts with t-shirt
Try shorts with bra
Try shorts with top
Try shorts with jacket
Try skirt with t-shirt
Try skirt with bra
Try skirt with top
Try skirt with jacket
```

Как мне исправить код, чтобы он заработал как надо???

Comment: А какие результаты должны быть?

Comment: `('jeans')` совсем не то что `('jeans', )`.

Comment: `fav == cloth or top_cloth` работает не так как вы думаете.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какой должен быть ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял вопрос, то надо поверять вхождение подбираемой верхней и нижней одежды в список избранных.
Код можно привести к подобному виду:

```
bottom_clothes = ('jeans', 'shorts', 'skirt')
top_clothes = ('t-shirt', 'bra', 'top', 'jacket')
favourites = ('jeans')

for cloth in bottom_clothes:
    for top_cloth in top_clothes:
        if any([cloth in favourites, top_cloth in favourites]):
            print(f'Try {cloth} with {top_cloth}')
```

Или, если нужно почти в одну строку:

```
for b, t in [[b,t] for b in bottom_clothes for t in top_clothes 
             if any([b in favourites, t in favourites])]:
    print(f'Try {b} with {t}')
```

Вывод

```
Try jeans with t-shirt
Try jeans with bra
Try jeans with top
Try jeans with jacket
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб

```py
bottom_clothes = ('jeans', 'shorts', 'skirt')
top_clothes = ('t-shirt', 'bra', 'top', 'jacket')
favourites = ('t-shirt','jeans')

for item_from_favourites in favourites:
    if item_from_favourites in bottom_clothes:
        for item in top_clothes:
            print(f"Try {item_from_favourites} with {item}")
    elif item_from_favourites in top_clothes:
        for item in bottom_clothes:
            print(f"Try {item_from_favourites} with {item}")
```

вывод

```py
Try t-shirt with jeans
Try t-shirt with shorts
Try t-shirt with skirt 
Try jeans with t-shirt 
Try jeans with bra     
Try jeans with top     
Try jeans with jacket
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```py
bottom_clothes = ('jeans', 'shorts', 'skirt')
top_clothes = ('t-shirt', 'bra', 'top', 'jacket')
favourites = ('jeans', 'bra')

clothes = (bottom_clothes, top_clothes)
for fav in favourites:
    for cloth in clothes[fav in bottom_clothes]:
        print(f'Try {fav} with {cloth}')
```

Вывод:

```
Try jeans with t-shirt
Try jeans with bra
Try jeans with top
Try jeans with jacket
Try bra with jeans
Try bra with shorts
Try bra with skirt
```