# Как проверить на много OR в python

Tags: python

Как возможно записать эту проверку легче?
Не печатая на каждый элемент проверки отдельный **OR**?
Может есть какая-то функция?

```
i = '123'
if '1' in i or '2' in i or '3' in i or '4' in i:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: `print(any(x in "123" for x in ['1','2','3']))`

Comment: кстати, всю эту проверку if-else можно записать как ``print('1' in i or '2' in i or '3' in i or '4' in i)``. Но это только если нужно напечатать True или False, для других действий так не пойдет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 5):

конечно можно. через set

```
i = '123'
c = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
print(bool(set(i) & c))
```

& - ищет пересечение множеств.

Answer (score 4):

```
test = "123"
check = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

print(any(x in test for x in check))
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Так называемый "функциональный" вариант (без использования циклов даже в таком виде как списковое включение, а одни только вызовы функций):

```
i = '123'
print(any(map(i.__contains__, '1234')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно поиграться с типом данных `set()`. То что нам нужно это пересечение множеств. Как это работает?

Кинем переменную `i` в тип `set` и присвоим значение для переменной `a`:

```py
>>> i = '123'
>>> a = set(i)
>>> a
{'1', '3', '2'}
```

Далее создадим некий шаблон (`pattern`) по которому и будем определять совпадения. Судя из вашего `if`'а:

```py
>>> pattern = set("1234")
```

А теперь глянем пересекаются ли они:

```py
>>> a & pattern
{'1', '3', '2'}
```

Или проверка с `if`:

```py
>>> if a & pattern == set():
...   print(False)
... else:
...   print(True)
```

Answer (score 3):

В качестве экзотики:

```
print(bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in '123', '1234'))))  # True
print(bool(sum(map(lambda x: x in '567', '1234'))))  # False
```

Comment: Можно на список не разбивать, строка сама разобьётся при применении `map` )

Comment: Спасибо) Упустил))) Копировал список у *strawdog*)))))