# Vk Api: Проблема с ботом

Tags: python, вконтакте

Вечер добрый! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: бот отвечает на сообщение вызывающее команду вместо последующего. Нагляднее покажу далее.

```
        def blasthack(id, text):
            bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:

        message = event.text.lower()
        id = event.user_id

        if message == 'название команды':

            blasthack(id, 'Введите любое что-то там')
        
            text = message 

            blasthack(id, 'Текст: ' + text)

            blasthack(id, 'типо текст')
```

Тут бот отвечает не на текст который вводит пользователь после активации команды, а на саму команду.

Привожу пример:

Я: название команды
Бот: Введите любое, что-то там
Бот: Текст: отзыв

Надеюсь понятно, объяснил.

Это первое. Второе, при добавлении в if оператор or - происходит интересная хренотень.
То есть:

```
 if message == 'тест' or 'test':
        blasthack(id, 'тест test')
 else:
        messages = ['Прости, я тебя не понял!', 'Ой, не расслышал, можешь повторить?', 'Я не 
        знаю это слово можешь перефразировать?']
        msg_fail = random2.choice(messages)
        blasthack(id, msg_fail )
```

Что-же выдаёт мне бот:

Я: тест
Бот: тест test
Я: test
Бот: тест test
Я: йгнапунгвфып
Бот: тест test ( вместо блока else )

P.s: знаю, что пишу максимально тупо и глупо, но после тяжёлого дня уже сил нет нормально и качественно всё расписывать, сел за дебаггинг и чуть не сдох. Надеюсь на помощь и желаю терпения тем кто откликнется на данный вопрос :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в условии `if`. Попробуйте так:

```py
if message == 'тест' or message == 'test':
```