# Почему функция or не работает с telebot? И как мне сделать обработчик чтоб проверял что ввел пользователь?

Tags: telebot

````
def message_handler(message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if text = 'hello' or 'hello!':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi!')```
````

Comment: Во-первых, вы написали не сравнение, а присваивание, а это синтаксически некорректно. Во-вторых, даже если вы пропишете сравнение, выражение `'hello!'` всегда считается истинным (потому что непустые строки всегда считаются истинными), а значит этот if будет всегда срабатывать. [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296)

Comment: @andreymal а как сделать чтоб если сообщение равняется текст1 или текст2 будет отвечать что-то? помогите пж

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже понял)