# Необходимо, чтоб из input я мог изменять значение уже объявленной переменной (Python)

Tags: python

Мне необходимо, чтобы переменная менялась, только в том случае, если пользователь введёт определённое значение, а не произвольное
к примеру

```py
    ...
    lang = 'RUS'
    def language():
        lang1 = input('Enter ENG or RUS: ')
        if lang1 == 'eng' or 'Eng' or 'ENG':
            lang = 'ENG'
        elif lang1 == 'rus' or 'Rus' or 'RUS':
            lang = 'RUS'
        else:
            print('You entered an incorrect value!')

    menu()
    command()
    ...
```

Необходимо чтоб после ввода какого-либо значения, переменная принимала значение введённое пользователем, подскажите как это можно сделать, заранее очень благодарен (Переменная будет не обязательно числовой).

Comment: этот код уже все делает как "необходимо",

Comment: Вы это и делаете сейчас. Когда вы в вопросе приводите код, нужно пояснять - почему вы считаете, что он делает не то, что вам нужно, в чём это выражается.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не правильно выразил мысль, фрагмент неработающего должным образом кода вставил в основном вопросе
Мне необходимо, чтобы переменная менялась, только в том случае, если пользователь введёт определённое значение, а не произвольное

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or/846307#846307

Comment: Запись в переменную lang внутри функции никак не влияет на глобальную переменную lang снаружи функции. Почитайте про использование глобальных переменных в python. Но вообще, лучше использовать возврат значения через return.

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно:

```
if lang1 == 'eng' or 'Eng' or 'ENG':
```

Правильно:

```
if lang1 == 'eng' or lang1 == 'Eng' or lang1 == 'ENG':
```

Ещё лучше:

```
if lang1.lower() == 'eng':
```

Comment: Приветствую, благодарю за ответ, данная проблема пока не решилась, не могли бы вы мне прислать вашу электронную почту, чтоб я вам прислал код, а то я сам точно не справлюсь...

Comment: legolashacker0@gmail.com

Comment: Благодарю, код выслал на почту