# как сделать чтоб в if переменная == "1 и 2 и 3 и так до 10 чтоб есть человек вводил 1 или 5 или 3 был один и тот же результат

Tags: python

```
n = input("назови число 5 - 10 ")
if n == "5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10":
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, например, можно проверять есть ли такая строка в списке строк:

```py
if n in ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]:
```

Если числа идут подряд, можно сделать так:

```py
if n in map(str, range(5, 11)):
```

Или наоборот привести строку в число и проверять уже вхождение числа в `range`:

```py
if int(n) in range(5, 11):
```

Comment: А банальное n >= 5 and n <= 10?

Comment: В таком случае надо в int число перевести сначала обязательно.

Comment: Не обязательно, строки тоже можно сравнить

Comment: спасибо огромно помогло!

Comment: @Ara_Bog только если мы сравниваем цифры. Числа строками будут сравниваться некорректно: попробуйте ```"10" < "2"```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("назови число 5 - 10 "))
if 5 <= n <= 10:
```

Вариантов много, вот мне кажется неплохой...