# Проблема с функцией для бота

Tags: python, функции

Всем привет, я недавно в этом удивительном мире и начал свой путь с питона. Я решил сделать простого "бота" для общения, но у меня возникает проблема с выводом. По идеи, отправляя данные в функцию, оно должно проходить через проверки пока не дойдет до нужной, но чтобы я не ввёл, всегда исполняется первая.

```
IA = True
print("Зравствуйте, сэр. Меня зовут Джарвис. Я простой искусственный интеллект")
def Intellect(msg):
    if msg == "Привет" or "Здравствуй" or "Интересно" or "Круто" or "Привет, Джарвис" or "Здравствуй, Джарвис":
        print("Как прошёл ваш день?")
    elif msg == "Джарвис?" or "Джарвис" or "Кто?" or "Кто":
        print("Джарвис - искусственный интеллект, первая версия от 17.03.2022.")
        print("Создан с целью практики в кодинге и от скуки")
        print("Версия №1. Надеюсь, меня сделают  лучше и подарят голос")
        print("Что-то ещё?")

while IA:
    data = input().lower().title()
    Intellect(data)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/python-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-or

Comment: учебники надо внимательнее читать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
if msg == "Привет" or msg == "Здравствуй" or msg ==  "Интересно" or msg ==  "Круто" or msg ==  "Привет, Джарвис" or msg ==  "Здравствуй, Джарвис":
        print("Как прошёл ваш день?")
```

Нужно добавлять `msg ==`.

Но я думаю что здесь будет намного удобнее проверять так:

```py
hello_words_list = ["привет", "здравствуй", "хай"] # здесь просто список слов которые могут встретиться в предложении

for word in msg: # сделайте ваш msg списком в котором буду слова по отдельности
    if word in hello_words_list: # если слово в списке
        # тут делайте что-то, например создайте функцию say_hello() которая напечатает в ответ приветсвие
```

Пишите мне если будут вопросы по боту. Я тоже делал что-то похожее только с распознованием речи и голосом.

Comment: Спорное утверждение, что нужно так писать. Я бы посоветовал вам PEP8 почитать и придерживаться его. У вас, хотя бы, длина строки не выдерживает критики

Comment: @Dmitry Для себя я бы писал совсем по-другому. Но так как вопрос был задан с целью узнать почему проверяется только первая проверка, я написал ему такой вариант. Если бы вопрос был бы как чище или правильней написать проверку -- я бы написал другое.

Comment: Я триггернул на "нужно писать так". По мне так не нужно так писать. Может предложить ТС'у более корректное решение? поскольку он указал, что опыта как такового нет. Вторая часть ответа более приятно смотрится, может на нее опереться? Просто предложение

Comment: я понял в чем моя ошибка, я забывал прописывать msg ==, так глупо)

Comment: @Dmitry Исправил

Comment: Плюс от меня за отзывчивость. Но PEP8 все равно почитайте)))

Comment: @Dmitry Обязательно)