# Проверка на вхождение одной строки в другую

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть переменная `fc` которая принимает значения: `R:\TEST\TESTXLS.xlsx` или `R:\TEST\TESTXLS.xls` для проверки расширения файла я использую

```
if 'xlsx' in fc:
```

при попытке использовать

```
if 'xlsx' or 'xls' in fc:
```

скрипт не срабатывает так как надо.

Как нужно написать чтобы правильно срабатывал ?

Comment: `if fc.find('.xls') ...` ? *для проверки расширения файла я использую `if 'xlsx' in fc:`* И как оно реагирует на `'R:\TEST.xlsx\TESTXLS.bmp'` ?

Comment: А питон именно второй?

Comment: Спасибо помогло, в переменной fc только эксель файлы, но на будущее нужно предусмотреть и вариант не с экселем

Comment: да версия python 2.7

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python и проблемы строчного “or”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/1365)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут сразу несколько ошибок. Например, это выражение всегда истинно:

```
'xlsx' or 'xls' in fc => ('xlsx') or ('xls' in fc) => True or ('xls' in fc) => True
```

Т.е. правильный код должен быть такой:

```
if 'xlsx' in fc or 'xls' in fc:
          ^^^^^
```

Имя файла лучше выделять из полного пути, чтобы не было ложных срабатываний, если в пути попадётся такая же строка, делать это можно с помощью `os.path.split`, и после этого уже проверять только имя файла. Ну и ещё нужно переводить в нижний регистр перед сравнением с помощью функции `lower()`, потому что имя файла может быть в любом регистре.

Но лучше всего выделять сразу расширение файла, для этого тоже есть специальная функция `os.path.splitext`.

Пример кода:

```
import os

paths = ["R:\TEST\TESTXLS.xlsx", "R:\TEST\TESTXLS.XLS", "R:\TEST.xlsx\TESTXLS.bmp"]
extensions = [".xls", ".xlsx"]
for filename in paths:
    head, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() in extensions:
        print(filename)
```

Вывод:

```
R:\TEST\TESTXLS.xlsx
R:\TEST\TESTXLS.XLS
```