# что значит эта строка? "Comparison is case-insensitive"

Tags: python

```
def xo(s):
    x = 0
    o = 0
    for i in s:
        if i == "x":
            x += 1
        elif i == "o":
            o += 1
        elif i == "X" or "O":
            pass
        else:
            pass

    if x == o:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: В смысле "что значит"? Перевод на русский, что ли, нужен?

Comment: Приведите текст задания, а то не понятен контекст ошибки. А так, гугл переводчик, думаю, однозначно переводит текст ошибки: "Сравнение не чувствительно к регистру"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @gil9red готово

Comment: @Эникейщик, я по этому сюда и пришел, мне из переводчика понятней не стало

Comment: @gil9red, Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any char.

Comment: Строка elif i == "X" or "O": делает не то, что вы думаете. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or

Answer (score 1):

В задании сказано, что функция не должна учитывать регистр символов, а ваша учитывает.

---

*Блок*

```
if x == o:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

*можно заменить на просто*

```
return o == x
```