# Значение с нуля само прибавляется на единицу

Tags: python

Задача была в том, чтобы на входе функции получить строку , в ней подсчитать все гласные буквы и вывести их количество. При этом если есть "y" она приравнивается к нулю . Почему в моём коде выводится единица а не ноль?

```
def get_count(sentence):
    sum = 0;
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    for i in sentence:
        if i == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
            sum += 1
        elif i == 'y':
            sum = sum + 0;

    return sum

print(get_count("y"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if i in 'аеиоу'`

Comment: прочитайте учебник - синтаксис OR, AND  и т.д. Вы его нарушили.

Comment: @Сергей дурацкое правило какое то, если нет истины , возвращается последнее значение

Comment: напишите свой Python, если хотите:-) Это правило вполне себе в духе текущего Python.

Comment: `sum = sum + 0;` - это не приравнивание нулю.

Comment: неверный синтаксис не дает ему сработать. Кстати, часть с `elif`  вообще тут можно удалить, суммирование с 0 ничего не даёт.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я понял, что сам y к 0 приравнивается. Если вся сумма, то да - `sum = 0` и `break`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильно писать с OR, AND и т.д. `if i == 'a' or 'e'` - сосгласно синтаксису первая проверка будет на `i == 'a'`, а вторая на `if 'e'`. Ясно, что вторая всегда даст `True`, так что до `elif` дело не дойдет.

Правильно писать:  `if i == 'a' or i == 'e'`

А лучше всего писать, как и написал @CrazyElf: `if i in 'аеиоу'`

Comment: Неправильно так писать,  как сказал многоуважаемый Crazy Elf, при запросе get_count('aeiou') python пишет, что строка такая найдена,  а не перечень символов входящие в строку

Comment: Потому, что никто не предлагал эту строку включать в запрос. Запрос остается ваш - `print(get_count("y"))`, это лишь замена OR. Кстати, "лучше" я написал потому, что этот способ рекомендован официальным руководством по языку.

Comment: А `sum = sum + 0` не смущает? Да ещё и с `;`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я выше писал об этом. Но сам вопрос о другом был, так что не фокусировался на этом.

Comment: @Сергей вот как решил задачу мастер)) как то навороченно))  def getCount(inputStr):
    return sum(1 for let in inputStr if let in "aeiouAEIOU")