# На одно действие 3 ключевых слов. (vk.api)

Tags: python, массивы, vkontakte-api, api, бот

#Профиль

```
                    if user.mode == 'reg_end':

                        if msg == 'профиль':

                            sender(id, f'[id{user.id}|{user.name}], твой профиль: \n   ID: {user.id} \n  ⭐ Уровень: {user.lvl} \n   Денег: {user.coin} $\n   В банке: {user.bank} \n   Опыт: {user.opyt} \n   Биткойн: {user.bit}\n Дата регистраци: {reg_date}', nazad_key)
                            
                            user.mode = 'reg_end'
```

Нужно чтоб реагировал на «профиль» «проф» «/prof»

Comment: `if(msg == 'рофиль' || '/prof' || 'проф')`, не знаю какой это ЯП, но если python - то вместо `||` юзайте `or` или что там у вас

Comment: @Aarnihauta, плохой совет, это всегда вернет true, т.к. там есть непустая строка (см. в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846307/201445). Лучше через оператор in проверять: `msg in ['профиль', 'проф', '/prof']`

Comment: @gil9red не в курсе тонкостей пайтона, я шарпист

Comment: @Aarnihauta, а вот на c# это вызвало проблему: `string text = "123"; if (text == "abc" || "123" || "999") {` - `Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код, все работает всем спасибо.

```
if msg == 'профиль' or msg == 'проф' or msg == '/prof':
```

Comment: `if msg in ('профиль', 'проф', '/prof'):` я бы советовал так - проще выглядит :)