# Не удаётся остановить бесконечный цикл)

Tags: python

Не могу остановить цикл. По какой то причине значение переменной program внутри функции repeat_program не изменяется

```
program = 1

def repeat_program(program):
        repeat = input("Повторить программу? ")
        if repeat == "да" and "Да" and "yes" and "1":
            print('Продолжаем вычисления')
            program == 1
        elif repeat == "нет" and "Нет" and "no" and "0":
            print('Всего хорошего')
            program == 0
        else:
            print('Такого варианта нет')
            repeat_program(program)


while program == 1:
    try:
        a = float(input('Введите делимое: '))
        b = float(input('Введите делитель: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Нельзя вводить строки')    
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Нельзя делить на ноль')
    except:
        print('Что-то пошло не так')
    else:
        c = a / b
        print('Частное: '+ str(c))
    finally:
        repeat_program(program)
```

[image: код с результатом]

Comment: Вот именно что значение переменной program меняется **внутри** функции repeat_program, а вот **снаружи** глобальную переменную program никто нигде не меняет

Comment: @andreymal не, внутри тоже не меняется :)

Comment: в этой программе примерно 30% строк делают совсем не то, что вам кажется. Начните с этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or, потом разберитесь в разнице между == и =.

Comment: После этого можете перечитать главу о try..except

Comment: Плюс еще рекурсия не к месту

Comment: Кстати, как вы себе представляете ситуацию, в которой repeat равно "да" и "Да" и "yes" и "1" одновременно?

Comment: Замените `program == 0` на функцию выхода `quit()`. Конечно, остальных ошибок не решит, но сам код заработает