# Как правильно передать несколько параметров в assert python?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

У меня есть цикл, который проверяет название товара

```
for search in search_products:
        assert (("наушники" or "гарнитура") in search.text.lower()), f'Error in product - \
                                                    {search.text, browser.save_screenshot("./screensots/screen3.png")}'
```

Но проверяется только первый параметр и я получаю ошибку

```
AssertionError: Error in product -                                                         ('-72%\nOzon\n560 ₽1 990 ₽\n10548 отзывы\nбеспроводная телефонная гарнитура TWS F9-5, bluetooth гарнитура для смартфона с микрофоном')
```

Как можно сделать проверку обоих параметров?

Comment: Попробуйте прописать 2 ассерта, с наушниками и отдельный с гарнитурой.
Если же не поможет, запишите функцию которая возвращает search.text Ваш список. Далее сравните функцию именно "==" или "!=", скорее всего проблема в равенстве. Могу ошибаться, но Вы попробуйте

Comment: 2 ассерта точно не поможет, потому что тогда он на одном провалится и ко второму не пойдет..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` в Python не работает так как в естественных языках, т.е. `"наушники" или "гарнитура" входят в search.text.lower()` нельзя напрямую перевести в код на Python. Оператор `or` так не работает, он просто проверяет что одно из значений (справа или слева от него) истинно, но не умеет как-то передавать сначала одно потом другое значение в `in` (или куда-то еще).

Для сравнения посмотрите похожую проблему, с которой сталкиваются новички: [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/1365) (вкратце, часто пытаются проверить равенство переменной одному из нескольких значений через `a == "X" or "Y"` или `a == ("X" or "Y")` - ни тот ни другой вариант не работает).

Фактически нужен прямо цикл, где каждый элемент из набора `("наушники", "гарнитура")` берется, и проверяется его наличие в `search.text.lower()`. Потом нужно проверить, что хотя бы один результат сравнения равен `True`. Это можно реализовать через выражение-генератор, потом результат проверить через `any`:

```
assert any(item in search.text.lower() for item in ("наушники", "гарнитура"))
```