# Возвращение к определенному участку кода

Tags: python, циклы

Есть код

```
choice = 1
choice_1 = 1
while choice == 1:
    user_name = str(input("Введите свой логин\n"))
    user_password = str(input("Введите свой пароль\n"))
    if file_text.find(user_name) != -1 and file_text.find(user_password) != -1:
        print("Вы успешно вошли в систему")
        break
    else:
        print("Неверный логин или пароль\n")
        choice_1 = str(input("Повторить?(Да - Нет)\n"))
        if choice_1 == "Нет" or "нет":
            choice = 0
        elif choice_1 == "Да" or "да":
            choice = 1
```

После вопроса о повторе ввода данных, при выборе "нет" программа должна завершаться, а при выборе "да" продолжаться, но она завершается при любых обстоятельствах.
Пробовал через цикл for

```
choice = 1
choice_1 = 0
for i in range(int(choice)):
    user_name = str(input("Введите свой логин\n"))
    user_password = str(input("Введите свой пароль\n"))
    if file_text.find(user_name) != -1 and file_text.find(user_password) != -1:
        print("Вы успешно вошли в систему")
        break
    else:
        print("Неверный логин или пароль\n")
        choice_1 = str(input("Повторить?(Да - Нет)\n"))
        if choice_1 == "Нет" or "нет":
            choice = 0
        elif choice_1 == "Да" or "да":
            choice = 1
```

Но с ним такая же проблема.

Comment: проблема тут `choice_1 == "Нет" or "нет"`. Нужно `choice_1 in ["Нет", "нет"]` или `choice_1 == "Нет" or choice_1 == "нет"`

Comment: А ветку с "Да" можно вообще убрать.

Comment: Спасибо, а можете ли вы объяснить в чем тут проблема?

Comment: @Aloterra посмотрите ответы к вопросу по ссылке, там подробно расписано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/1365