# Реализация макс-кучи в Python

Tags: python

В цикле обрабатывается команда из промта: если в команде нет `'insert'` или `'pop'` или `'end'`, то значит идёт ряд чисел в формате `str`.  При этом  условии я добавляю в кучу отрицательные значения из промта, чтобы реализовать макс-кучу.

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify

heap = []
heapify(heap)

while (promt:= input()) != 'end':
    if 'insert' or 'pop' not in promt:
        for p in promt.split():
            heappush(heap, -1 * int(p))
    elif 'insert' in promt:
        heappush(heap, -1 * int(promt.split()[1]))
    elif 'pop' in promt:
        print(-1 * (heappop(heap)))
```

при этом вылетает ошибка:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'insert'
```

получается `'insert'` игнорирует условие или как? Подскажите, где я мог допустить ошибку

На вход подаётся следующие значения:

```
1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
insert 20
pop
insert 0
pop
insert 4
pop
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Связанный вопрос: [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/846296/1365)</sub>

Условие `if 'insert' or 'pop' not in promt:` работает совсем не так, как вы думаете:

**`or` не перечисляет значения справа и слева от него**, а является логической операцией (логическое "ИЛИ", оно же [дизъюнкция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)). В Python он имеет имеет дополнительные особенности: он возвращает первое не ложное значение среди его операндов.

`'insert' or 'pop' not in promt` на самом деле вычисляется как `'insert' or ('pop' not in promt)`, и результатом `or` будет первое не ложное значение среди его операндов, в данном случае - `'insert'` (т.к. любая не пустая строка считается истинным значением), до вычисления `('pop' not in promt)` дело вообще не дойдет. В итоге ваш `if` превратится в `if 'insert':`, "условие" у него всегда истинно, поэтому всегда выполняется первая ветка `if`.

Даже если обернуть в скобки `('insert' or 'pop') not in promt` - выражение в скобках превратится просто в `'insert'`, все выражение превратится в `'insert' not in promt`.

Правильно ваше условие должно выглядеть так:

```
if 'insert' not in promt and 'pop' not in promt:
```

Между частями именно `and`, потому что для первой ветки нужно чтобы обе стороны не были истинными одновременно.

Тут полезно знать [законы де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) (при внесении отрицания в скобки отрицание применяется к операндам, и при этом `or` меняется на `and` и наоборот). Если вынести отрицание за скобки, получится такое условие:

```
if not ('insert' in promt or 'pop' in promt):
```

Но вообще проще всего исправить, перенеся первую ветку `if` в `else`

```
if 'insert' in promt:
    heappush(heap, -1 * int(promt.split()[1]))
elif 'pop' in promt:
    print(-1 * (heappop(heap)))
else:
    for p in promt.split():
        heappush(heap, -1 * int(p))
```