# Не могу разобраться с or

Tags: python, if

Не могу понять почему:

```
if 'something' in query or 'anything' in query:
    print(1)
```

и

```
if 'something' or 'anything' in query:
    print(1)
```

Не одно и то же.

Comment: потому что таков синтаксис языка.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or)

Comment: Дубликат-дубликатом, а минус-то за что автору?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да не одно и тоже.

1. `if 'something' in query` - тут ты проверяешь на на явность чего-то в списке.
2. `if 'something'` - тут оно ВСЕГДА будет возвращать `True`, потому `in query` относиться только ко второй части (`'anything' in query`).