# Помогите разобратся в коде. Я новичок

Tags: python

```
print("Привет это конвентор валют он может переводить в евро доллары и рубли")

    while True:
        dolar=(99)
        euro=(104)
    
        def1=input("Введите из какой валюты переводить:")
        def3=int(input("А сколько валюты?:"))
        def2=input("В какуювалюту переводить:")
        if def1==("евро") or ("Евро") and def2==("рубль") or def2==("Рубли") or def2==("рубли") or def2== ("Рубль"):
            c=def3*euro
            print(c)
        elif def1 ==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль") and def2==("евро") or ("Евро"):
            c=def3/euro
            print(c)
        elif def1==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль") and def2==("долар") or ("Долар"):
            c=def3/dolar
            print(c)
        elif def1==("долар") or ("Долар") and def2==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль"):
            c=def3*dolar
            print(c)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ошибка в 9 строке кода

Comment: Ошибка не только в 9 строке (кстати, это какая именно?). Тут достаточно ошибок в разных строчках.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or

Answer (score 1):

Вместо конструкций типа

```
def1==("евро") or ("Евро")
```

используйте

```
def1 in ("евро", "Евро")
```

Везде в вашем коде, где вы такую конструкцию найдете.

---

*Объяснение:*

Вы вероятно хотели — в форме, которую Питон понимает сходно с вами — такое:

```
(def1 == "евро") or (def1 == "Евро")        # скобки не нужны, но делают код более четким
```

Это можете тоже использовать, но выражение

```
def1 in ("евро", "Евро")
```

короче и красивее.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть переменные dolar и euro, но они назначены неправильно. Вы должны использовать оператор = для присвоения значений, например:

```
dolar = 99
euro = 104
```

if - есть проблемы в условиях, должны быть написаны так:

```
if def1 == "евро" or def1 == "Евро" and (def2 == "рубль" or def2 == "Рубли" or def2 == "рубли" or def2 == "Рубль"):
```

Вы должны проверять каждую переменную (def1 и def2) отдельно, и используйте скобки для ясности.

Внутри каждого блока if вы используете "c", чтобы сохранить результат. Но вам также нужно учесть, что вы выбираете операцию умножения или деления в зависимости от направления конвертации. Например:

```
if def1 == "евро" or def1 == "Евро" and (def2 == "рубль" or def2 == "Рубли" or def2 == "рубли" or def2 == "Рубль"):
    c = def3 * euro  # Если конвертация из евро в рубли
    print(c)
```

не забудьте добавить возможность выхода из бесконечного цикла, например, при вводе команды "выход" или "exit".

Пример кода:

```
print("Привет, это конвертер валют. Он может переводить в евро, доллары и рубли.")
dolar = 99
euro = 104

while True:
    def1 = input("Введите из какой валюты переводить (евро, доллар или рубль): ").lower()
    if def1 == "выход":
        break

    def2 = input("В какую валюту переводить (евро, доллар или рубль): ").lower()
    if def2 == "выход":
        break

    def3 = float(input("Введите количество валюты: "))

    if def1 == "евро" and (def2 == "рубль" or def2 == "рубли"):
        c = def3 * euro
        print(c)
    elif def1 == "рубль" and def2 == "евро":
        c = def3 / euro
        print(c)
    elif def1 == "рубль" and def2 == "доллар":
        c = def3 / dolar
        print(c)
    elif def1 == "доллар" and (def2 == "рубль" or def2 == "рубли"):
        c = def3 * dolar
        print(c)
    else:
        print("Неправильный ввод. Попробуйте еще раз.")
```

Comment: x = 1 и x = (1) дают одинаковый результат, x будет равно 1. Если в скобках только один объект (число, строка итп), то переменной присваивается этот сам объект.

Comment: Несомненно, но привыкать нужно к flake8)

Answer (score 0):

в переменной otvet хранится ответ на вопрос "Как у тебя дела?" на такой вопрос можно ответить через консоль

```
otvet= input("Как у тебя дела?")
```

следующая строка кода значит:
если переменная otvet равна Нормально, то отвечаю 'вот и отлично'
if - если
otvet - переменная
== проверка на равенство
'Нормально' - вторая переменная
: - то...
print('вот и отлично') - если условия выполняются, то выполняется эта команда

```
if otvet == 'Нормально':
    print('вот и отлично')
```

переменной verable присваевается значение 4

```
verable = 4
```

здесь уже проверяется 2 условия, вместо 'and' можно подставить 'or', тогда условия будут проверятся как: 3 равно 4 или 45 равно 45, тогда...

```
if 3 == 4 and 45 == 45:
    print('привет')
```

вывод в консоль "Хай"

```
print('Хай')
```

Это условия работает аналагично:
если ... равно ... или ... равно ... или ... равно ..., то будет ...

```
if def1==("евро") or ("Евро") and def2==("рубль") or def2==("Рубли") or def2==("рубли") or def2== ("Рубль"):
    c=def3*euro
    print(c)
```

Условие если оценка равна 5 то... понятно
Но что же такое elif?

```
if ozhenka == 5:
    print('Пять за год в 8-м классе мо матеше!')
```

если прошлое условие не выполнилось(оценка не равна 5), то проверяется
следующие условие:
если оценка равна 4, то...

```
elif ozhenka == 4:
    print('4 тоже хорошо.')
```

эти циклы работают аналагично, если подумаешь, то разберёшься)

```
elif def1 ==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль") and def2==("евро") or ("Евро"):
    c=def3/euro
    print(c)
elif def1==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль") and def2==("долар") or ("Долар"):
    c=def3/dolar
    print(c)
elif def1==("долар") or ("Долар") and def2==("рубль") or ("Рубли") or ("рубли") or ("Рубль"):
    c=def3*dolar
    print(c)
```