# Почему программа когда выполняется условие с точкой говорит да

Tags: python

```
string = input()
if '@' and '.' in string:
    print('Да')
else:
    print('Нет')
```

Вообщем делал задачку по курсу. Задание выглядит так

> А где может понадобиться оператор in, кроме игры в слова?
>
> Чаще всего при проверке корректности текста. Например, когда
> пользователь вводит на сайте свой адрес электронной почты.
>
> Будем считать e-mail адрес корректным, если в нём есть символы «@» и
> «.». Напиши программу, проверяющую, что почта введена верно.

Так вот я не пойму почему программа когда выполняется условие с точкой программа говорит да? При and же должно выполнятся только при выполнении всех условий . _ .

[image]

Comment: У вас в if прописано два выражения через and: `'@'` и `'.' in string`. Любая непустая строка всегда считается истинной, поэтому первое выражение `'@'` автоматически истинно. В введённой вами строке есть точка — поэтому второе выражение `'.' in string` тоже истинно. Наконец, сравниваем их через and: `истина and истина` — очевидно, тоже истина, и всё условие if успешно выполняется

Comment: Поставим скобки для ясности: `if ('@') and ('.' in string):` -> `if True and ('.' in string):` -> `if '.' in string:`

Comment: (в каком-то смысле вопрос является вывернутым наизнанку вопросом [Неправильно работает сравнение переменной с несколькими значениями через or](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if '@' and '.' in string:
```

значит

```
if ('@') and ('.' in string):
```

потому что оператор `and` имеет очень низкий приоритет.

Теперь, первый операнд, т.е. `'@'` вычисляется как `True`, потому что [каждая **непустая** строка так вычисляется](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) (и только пустая, т.е. `''`, вычисляется как `False`.)

Из документации в предыдущей ссылке:

> По умолчанию объект считается **истинным**.
> ... большинство встроенных объектов, считающихся ложными:
>
> - константы, определяемые как ложные: None и False.
> - ноль любого числового типа: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - **пустые последовательности и коллекции: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)**

Но когда первый операнд операции `and` вычисляется как `True`, то [результат будет равен второму операнду](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/stdtypes.html#and-or-not).

Из документации в предыдущей ссылке:

> x and y       если x false, тогда x, **иначе y**

Значит, ваша команда

```
if '@' and '.' in string:
```

имеет тот же эффект как команда

```
if '.' in string:
```

**игнорирующая присутствие или отсутствие символа `@`,** что вы очевидно не хотели.

---

Вы хотели

```
if '@' in string and '.' in string:
```

Comment: Всё относительно. Относительно `in` у `and` действительно ниже приоритет. А вот был бы там `or`, относительно него у `and` приоритет выше. )