# Ошибка: TypeError, string without an encoding

Tags: python, requests

Я делаю программу для активации используя ключ, ключ сравнивается с сервером
Код:

```
import requests 
 
content_site = requests.get("http://therussiaweather.atwebpages.com/keys.txt") 
 
keys = bytes(list(content_site.content)) 
 
print(keys) 
 
user_key = bytes(input("Введите ключ: ")) 
 
if user_key.upper() in keys: 
    for i in range(len(keys)): 
        if user_key.upper() == keys[i]: 
            print("Активировано") 
else: 
    print("Не активировано")
```

Сервер:

```
["GHG-GHG", "HGH-HGH"]
```

UPD: проблема с ошибкой решена, но у меня не выводиться print после условия

Comment: Полный трейсбэк, пожалуйста.

Comment: user_key = bytes(input("Введите ключ: "), 'utf-8') может кодировку добавить?

Comment: @Amgarak эта проблема решена, но мне не выводиться print, активировалось или нет

Comment: @timursper значит условие if user_key.upper() == keys[i]:  выкидывает False

Comment: @Amgarak это условие выполняется только если есть ключ в списке, как такое может быть?

Comment: @timursper так выведите через принт и посмотрите что получаете user_key.upper() = b'["GHG-GHG", "HGH-HGH"]' \ keys[i] = 91

Comment: @Amgarak как я могу это исправить?

Comment: @timursper, после `for i in range(len(keys)): ` добавьте строку `print(f'{user_key.upper()} == {keys[i]} : {user_key.upper() == keys[i]}')`

Comment: @HerrAskin b'GHG-GHG' == 91 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 34 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 45 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 34 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 44 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 32 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 34 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 45 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 71 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 72 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 34 : False
b'GHG-GHG' == 93 : False

Comment: что именно не выводится?

Comment: @Эникейщик "Активировано" в условии ```if user_key.upper() == keys[i]: ```. Ранее было выявлено что значения числовые, как их вернуть в исходный вариант?

Comment: А почему должно? Ты сравниваешь строку с байтом, они никогда не будут равны, потому и условие не выполняется.

Comment: @Эникейщик как байты переконвертировать в строку?

Comment: Так зачем ты вообще изначально переводишь все в байты?

Comment: @Эникейщик если не конвертировать, будут числовые значения:
Без конвертирования: ```[91, 34, 71, 72, 71, 45, 71, 72, 71, 34, 44, 32, 34, 72, 71, 72, 45, 72, 71, 72, 34, 93]```

Comment: замени ``bytes(list(content_site.content)) `` на ``content_site.text``, получишь сразу текст файла как текст. Но это будет еще не список! Надо будет его переделать в список.

Comment: Лучше записывай в файле ключи по одному на строчке и без всяких скобок и кавычек, будет намного проще.

Comment: @Эникейщик если так делать, то каждая буква будет отдельно

Comment: Разумеется, если итерироваться по строке, то будет каждай буква отдельно. Читай все, что я пишу, а не только первое предложение. Ну и разумеется, код, который написан для байтов, придется переделать. Ты думал, что изменишь исходный данные и у тебя прежний код станет правильно работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может не мудрить?

```
import requests
import json

# Получаем ключи
content_site = requests.get("http://therussiaweather.atwebpages.com/keys.txt")
keys_json = content_site.content.decode('utf-8')
keys_list = json.loads(keys_json)
print(keys_list)

# Ввод пользователя
user_key = input("Введите ключ: ")

# Проверяем, есть ли введенный ключ в списке
if user_key.upper() in keys_list:
    print("Активировано")
else:
    print("Не активировано")
```

Comment: А если ключей будет больше, чем 2? Например, 100, мне также писать:
if .... == keys[0], keys[1], keys[2] и т. д.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846296/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-or

Comment: @timursper да не вопрос, добавим библиотеку json и хоть миллион ключей будет.

Comment: А минус то за что?^^

Comment: @Amgarak я его не ставил, решение годное. Хотя если посмотреть на неотредактированный ответ, то там будет ошибка

Comment: @timursper Спору нет, немного поспешил)) Удачи.

Comment: У ответа есть метод json(), поэтому можно сразу записать `keys_list = content_site.json()`